# Limit number of rows per page in ReportViewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I've got a ReportViewer control setup and working (running in local mode), but it is currently displaying 43 rows per page.  I would like to change this to 25 per page, but am not sure how to accomplish this.  I have searched and found a few ways to accomplish this, but none have worked.

There is no option in the ReportViewer control for this that I have seen and the RDLC file doesn't appear to have anything in its xml for this either.  Any ideas?

Environment: ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms, Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a group to your report and use the following expression to group on:

`=Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)) / 25)`

Also set the 'Page break at and' property for the group.